How can I overlap div elements with Bootstrap 4?
I'm trying to achieve a the same overlapping  elements same as the file attached. I ws wondering the best code to do it.
I'm using bootstrap 4.6.2, does it can help?
Thanks for your advice.

So far I've can make it work with this code. But I'm not sure that is the best way since I have to adjust the 'top' position as the text and div height change.


.text-container {
  top: 44%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 75%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10% 4% 14% 2% !important;
}

.border-danger {
  border-color: #FF6F61 !important;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.text-danger {
  color: #FF6F61 !important;
}

.list-group-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

a.list-group-item:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.img-fluid {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.image-right {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#coaching-img {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6%;  
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-rt/SrQ4UNIaGfDyEXZtNcyWvQeOq0QLygHluFQcSjaGB04IxWhal71tKuzP6K8eYXYB6vJV4pHkXcmFGGQ1/0w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<section id="main_content" class="">
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-md-12 position-relative d-flex justify-content-end">
        <div class="text-container border border-danger rounded p-4">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2 class="text-danger">Profitez d'un accompagnement et de coaching personnalisé</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non est vitae nulla porttitor fringilla id eu dui. Donec eget cursus ex. Maecenas bibendum sodales augue.</p>
            <div class="list-group">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  Bloc de 1 heure <span>&#x2192;</span>
                </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  Bloc de 3 heures <span>&#x2192;</span>
                </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  Bloc de 5 heures <span>&#x2192;</span>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <img id="coaching-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Coaching Image" class="img-fluid rounded image-right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Bootstrap doesn't have facilities to do this. I suggest using negative right margin and matching right padding on the left column element in your custom stylesheet.

Starting from your code I've tried to simplify the structure in order to help you figure out how it works. I hope I've achieved what you were looking for, if not let me know in the comments.
The structure
Basically the text part is a bootstrap column of 9/12th (75% of the width), with a nested column of the same percentage (again 75% of the width), which is used to add the blank part on the right. Instead of a bootstrap column for the white space I could have used a fixed size padding, but it's completely a matter of taste.
In order to push the image to the right and to the bottom of the page, I've given a position: relative; style to the .container and a position: absolute; to the image. At this point, by giving a bottom and right position of 0 to the image, I was able to stick it to the bottom right corner of the container. To push it a little bit down I've given a negative margin.
For the z-index part I gave a position: relative; and z-index: 2; style to .text-container.
The code


.container{
  position: relative;
}

.text-container {
  padding: 36px 28px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
  
.border-danger {
  border-color: #FF6F61 !important;
  border: solid 1px;
}
  
.text-danger {
  color: #FF6F61 !important;
}
  
.list-group-item {
  border: 0;
  padding: 18px 0 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
 
.list-group-item:last-child {
  border-radius: 0;
}

a.list-group-item:hover {
  color: #000;
}
  
.img-fluid {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
  
#coaching-img {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 500px; */
  width: 44%;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: -46px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-rt/SrQ4UNIaGfDyEXZtNcyWvQeOq0QLygHluFQcSjaGB04IxWhal71tKuzP6K8eYXYB6vJV4pHkXcmFGGQ1/0w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="text-container border border-danger">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h2 class="text-danger">Profitez d'un accompagnement et de coaching personnalisé</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non est vitae nulla porttitor fringilla id eu dui. Donec eget cursus ex. Maecenas bibendum sodales augue.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Bloc de 1 heure <span>&#x2192;</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Bloc de 3 heures <span>&#x2192;</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Bloc de 5 heures <span>&#x2192;</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="coaching-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Coaching Image" class="img-fluid rounded">
  </div>
</body>
</html>



What wasn’t working in the original code
First thing you gave a style of position: relative; to the image and a position: absolute; to the .text-container: to do what the layout suggests you should give a position: relative; to the parent, and position: absolute; to the element that you want to force (in this case the image), which should be a direct child of the relative positioned element.
Another issue was giving a top position instead of a bottom one to the image.
And finally, the usage of percentages can create problems for paddings and margins: in most cases it's better to use fixed values. Using it for positions (top, bottom, etc.) is also risky sometimes. One issue with percentages is that sometimes it's not obvious which value they're a percentage of (the whole width, the whole height, a parent's width?). Another issue is that percentages often change when resizing the screen, so what works in one viewport may not work in another. Sometimes, when using percentages for those values, even a small resize can change a lot in the positioning of the elements in the page.
Final note
I've only managed the desktop version, the rest is not managed but can be improved with a couple of changes.
